# Details for SE(3) being a manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

As a student of engineering, i read that SE(3) is a manifold which commonly is known to us as a transformation matrix.

I have read proofs showing that a sphere is a 2-dimensional manifold. The proof has 3 components:-

1. the set
2. the topology assumed on the set
3. defining charts

For sphere the set is already given and the topology assumed is the standard one on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thereafter they explicitly write down the 4 charts that maps this sphere to the plane.

This proof is very common so could be found easily. But i have not been able to find such an explicit proof characterizing these 3 ingredients of proving SE(3) as manifold. On which set are we talking about what topology and how this structure can be explicitly shown to be euclidean locally?

A detailed proof from scratch PLUS connection of this mathematical structure to the physical significance of transformation matrices in robotics would be appreciated. Or reference to that effect will also be helpful.

Comment: $\text{SE}(3)$ is a set consisting of (certain types of) matrices; $\text{SE}(3)$ itself is not a "transformation matrix," as you say, but a collection of them.  As a smooth manifold, $\text{SE}(3)$ is the same as the Cartesian product $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \text{SO}(3)$.  So, one would want to understand: (1) how $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a manifold; (2) how $\text{SO}(3)$ is a manifold, and (3) how $M \times N$ is a manifold, whenever both $M,N$ are manifolds.

Comment: While what Jesse says is true, these are not equal tasks: (2) is tremendously harder than the others; this is the essential core of the question. I would break (2) into two further tasks, hinging on the observation that $\text{SO}(3)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{RP}^3$. (2.1) understand this homeomorphism, and (2.2) understand the smooth structure on $\Bbb{RP}^3$. The latter, at least, can be found in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. I would not be surprised if the former could as well; Lee is a rather comprehensive book.

Comment: @JesseMadnick That makes it quite clear, and an extra question, SO(3) is a manifold so how does this connect to physical rotations in real world. Is there a resource that can shed light on this connection also? Is it the similar to how we say that the unit circle corresponds to $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: @GoCodes: Saying that an object $X$ is a manifold just means (loosely speaking) that your object $X$ is a shape that is locally euclidean. Being a manifold, in and of itself, is unrelated to rotations or transformations or anything like that. Completely separately, sets like $\text{SO}(3)$ and $\text{SE}(3)$ are not just manifolds, but _matrix groups_. This means (among other things) that they are sets whose elements are matrices. Matrices can be thought of as linear transformations of some $\mathbb{R}^n$. To repeat: $\text{SO}(3)$ and $\text{SE}(3)$ are both manifolds _and_ matrix groups.